# When do new things get added to the Java API

Tags: java

I have been wondering about this for a while and I can’t really find a clear answer. You see the standard Java API is really big and it includes a lot of different libraries and classes for you to use from GUI design to sending data over the Internet to basic things like sending a String to the console.

It also includes things like reading MIDI generating secure random Strings, things that seem really specific. But at the same time there doesn’t seem to be any standard JSON libraries available while JSON is an universal way of sending data between systems.

So what I want to know is: When does something get added to the Java API? What does something need to be considered to be added to the API?

Comment: It is a fairly broad question, but might work really well on Quora.  The answer is that "it depends."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your reply, I was afraid it might be too broad.

Comment: I'm not sure it is broad: looks like the (good) answer below can point to a single source.

Comment: I was wondering the same, you've beaten me too it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a "framework" that drives how new features "get" into java; to manifest themselves later on as new language elements or libraries.

Enter ... the [Java Community Process](https://www.jcp.org/en/home/index)!

Meaning: this is a forum where people make suggestions; which then get discussed; and at some point are either "added to Java somehow"; or rejected.

And for starters: the JSON-P project about a JSON processing API was/is driven by the jcp, see entry [374](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374).

Finally: but you are correct, not everything that shows up in the "standard library" should be there; whereas other important parts take way too long before people can agree on a proposal. And of course, there is also a long history of evolution.

So: when you could restart Java from scratch; you would organize things in a different way (and to a certain degree, that is what Java9 is trying to enable with the new [module](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2878952/java-platform/modularity-in-java-9.html) concept).

Comment: Nice. To add, they ain't as smart as these dudes: https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee

Comment: Please. Don't get us into a discussion now ;-) ... because would exactly prove that this question should have been closed instead of answered ;-) x2 ... but I can't resist. What do you mean? Do you regerd the C++ iso process to be more effective than the java approach?

Comment: @GhostCat: I can't resist either. Indeed I do. Java bodges: Generics, autoboxing, autounboxing, `==` for references, the -128 to +127 cached `Integer`, that `string` class with its `+` for concatenation, the list goes on and on.

Comment: Don't forget the date API, which was arguably broken for years, forcing many developers to rely on things like JodaTime.  Oh yeah, and also bad for not introducing generics from Java 1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen .... *Legendary Badge bearer #218* ... I was always wondering if it is *okay* to boast about such things. Now I know ;-) ... congratulations. I still have 78 days to go ... but I hope to get there by xmas or so. xmas 17 that is.

Comment: @GhostCat I copied Tim Schmelter's [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter), which advertises all his medals +1

Comment: @Bathsheba And to finalize that discussion: I agree with you folks, these are good examples that point out issues that should / could have been fixed long ago. On the other hand, I am still glad that I can spend most of my time with Java, and not C++. When we do code reviews for C++, we spent 80% of the time talking about the *how* the problem was solved; not the solution itself. And I find it truly annoying that each and any line of C++ can nowadays have a lot of "hidden" semantics. You have to know zillions of things to understand what code is doing. Sad.